# What method should I use instead of Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query::addExpression()?

Tags: entities, 9

I am using Entity Query to select nodes of two different types. The fetching seems to be working, but I want to sort the returned values. Both the content types have different date fields. I know I could do this with

```php
$query->addExpression('COALESCE( field_date_1, field_date_2)', 'Date'); 
$query->sort('Date', 'DESC');
```

but `addExpression()` isn't an existing method, and the code throws this exception.

> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query::addExpression()

How can I sort on two or more date fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entity queries don't support expressions. To get it around it, add a tag to the query:

```
$query->addTag('mymodule');
```

Then implement [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/9.2.x), check for the tag, and add the expression there instead:

```
function mymodule_query_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query instanceof Drupal\Core\Database\Query\SelectInterface && $query->hasTag('mymodule')) {
    $query->addExpression('...');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and hook_query_TAG_alter() too works here. Adding for future references.